# Share wifi configuration in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, external-accessory

I'm not trying to reproduce this at all, but I've just watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cpruzqm3M7Q), and am wondering how is the wifi configuration sent to the weather station.

You can see it around 1:20.

From what I know, to access wifi configurations, you'd have to be jailbroken and use private APIs, and yet, [Netatmo](http://www.netatmo.com) is available on the AppStore.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you looked into the possibilities in terms of hardware accessories connected to an iOS device? I am fairly certain you are able to do a bunch of things with the accessories and hardware APIs that isn't available unless you're using hardware.

Comment: You're probably right. You can't access the external framework full documentation unless you're registered as an accessory developer, can you ?

Comment: I don't think your statement "You can't access the external framework full documentation unless you're registered as an accessory developer" is right. Its totally up to manufacturer of third party hardware, whether you can have access to framework & doc or not ..Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the video.. I don't know what exactly they are doing. But as I am also working on similar stuff for my company, I can suggest you to achieve the same. As in video, they connected exteral hardware with iPhone through USB interface. they must be having some wifi module in there hardware. through USB interface, may be they are requesting wifi settings of hardware from iPhone, & then are creating ad-hoc network. As they have access to firmware, they can configure any type of network they want using iPhone. They just have to have USB interface working properly. So here you are not accessing wifi settings of iPhone, but of external hardware. Let me know if more info needed, or any edits in my answer .:)

**EDIT** About Ad-hoc & Infrastructure mode... I was not focusing on that sorry. As I've already mentioned about ah-hoc, in case of infrastructure mode, the firmware(Inside external hardware) device can take wifi host address from iPhone (using ifaddrs), then request host for an IP. (Can be static or dynamic). Now it can inform about allotted IP to iPhone. All these happened using USB interface, and now as everything is set, we are good to go. Let me know if I am still missing some points ..:)

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood you right. You mean the weather station isn't indeed connected to your home (or whatever) wifi, but to your iPhone through a ad hoc connection ? If that's it, wouldn't that mean that the station wouldn't work whenever you leave your home ?

Comment: Basically saying the same thing as my comment above; as a hardware accessory you get more access to stuff like Wi-Fi settings.

Comment: @runmad .. yeah you can say that. It looks like I just elaborated the point you made there. But trust me, I know what I am talking about.  :)